# Virtual environment wrappers for globally installed Python scripts

Tags: python, python-venv

I have a (rather specialist) software package with numerous programs which needs to be installed globally (i.e., into `/usr/local/bin`) and called by numerous users on the target machine *including system users*.   A few of these programs are Python, and I've managed dependencies so-far by a hard requirement that the only packages these scripts can use are those available as OS-provided packages.  Typically the target machine is Debian, and that has a good selection of Python packages, so this is not a huge restriction.

I'm investigating whether this requirement could be relaxed using Python's native venv.  So the outline would be that at package install, a venv with all of the modules that all of the programs need would be installed in `/usr/local/lib/<pkg>` somewhere, the Python scripts would be installed in `/usr/local/lib/<pkg>/libexec`, then for each we have a wrapper script (in `/usr/local/bin`) which runs the real script under the venv.  Keeping the venv up-to-date for the set of scripts looks to be a feasible task for me to take on.

I can't find much online on implementing this sort of approach, am I missing something?

Please note: A per-user approach would not work for my use-case, some of the users of these scripts will be system users who do not have home directories, sometimes it will be root and so-on.

Comment: could these utilities by containerized?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand -- I guess they could, but only if exposed outside the container to the target machine where work will be done, and then what is gained apart from complexity?

Comment: Any custom env could be constructed inside the context of the container.

Comment: I'm sure it could, but what is the advantage to just installing the venv in an ordinary directory on the target machine?

Comment: You can try that as well, I thought some of the issue was that you wanted to be certain that your specialized list of pre-requisites were properly installed in a manner that was sure not to mess up your system and be consistent for every user. You could likely do that with anaconda but I personally prefer using a container. I have run into situations where students have tried installing stuff via conda and pip back and forth and messed up their envs and sometimes their classmate's envs attempting to show them how to get things done.

Comment: No students involved here, the users will be technically proficient, or will be system users like `cron`, `root`.  The point is rather to have programs who's Python dependencies are reliably controlled.